# TCP - Client Synchronization

Tags: flash, tcp

I'm working on a networked flash game using TCP sockets (forced to use TCP b/c of flash). The game is pretty simple as it is mostly a text based game. The only real synchronization that must be enforced is a countdown timer for each client. This timer will start at 60 seconds and countdown to 0 and at 0 some game state change will occur, so it is important that all clients get to 0 at a similar time.

I could send the "start countdown" command from my server to all clients and use the clients system clock, but if the packet is dropped or delayed then a client could get out of sync with the others. I could also enforce some client/server protocol where the client must "check in" with the server every second (or less) and the server enforces the sync of all clients. My concern with this is efficiency. My game is a slow paced text game so it is very possible that a client may not have any data to send to the server for up to 30 seconds at a time.

It may not be possible to avoid the "constantly checking in" situation, but I'm hoping someone can give me some pointers to an efficient solution for keeping a timer in sync between multiple clients in a flash application.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I don't think NTP is possible with flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine the situation when some of the clients falls behind - what will you do?

I mean, imagine, there is a perfect synchronization, but one of the clients goes off-line during the countdown. Is the whole event canceled, or do the rest of the clients still "participate"?

There is a mechanism the video streaming servers employ for streaming video to Flash. They send a packet of a fixed size many times and measure the time it takes to travel back and forth (the Flash client is supposed to reply with a fixed size packet too). So, this allows to record the latency that exists between the server time and the client. Possibly, you could have built a lookup table per clients and send the message considering the delay - if that's not good enough... that seems to fall in the scientific research category, rather then games :) So, maybe asking users to install additional software / plugins wouldn't be a problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm wondering if this would work: I have the server start its own timer and then tell all clients to start the same timer on their system. The server then ignores any client requests that come in past the timer countdown to avoid a client being behind by a second or 2 and making some invalid request.